# Conditonally wrap line in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to be able to wrap a line conditionally.

if it matches a regex pattern then it doesn't wrap.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 8):

I believe you can call `editor.updateOptions({ wordWrap: "off" })` to switch between the states after the editor has been created.
Depending on your code you could call this function when your condition is true or false