# Implement word wrap in Monaco Editor, React

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco editor in my project for yml code typing. Is there any option to add word wrapper in Monaco editor in React.

Code:

```
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react"; //how imported

//Calling editor like this
<Editor
   theme="vs-dark"
   defaultLanguage="yaml"
   onChange={handleChangeMetho}
   value={value}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this stack overflow discussion has the answer. It seems the monaco editor has the wordwrap option. You would set a variable to the created editor and then update the option.
[Conditonally wrap line in Monaco Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466716/conditonally-wrap-line-in-monaco-editor)